# SSIS/SSDT Censor Characters in Specific Positions With Flat File

Tags: ssis, ssdt

I'm developing an ETL process via SSIS/SSDT, which works with Fixed-Width Flat Files. It has 3 record types, and one of them I need to censor specific characters at a certain position. Does anyone know of any documentation that covers steps relating to replacing characters in a specific record type, at a certain position? I've scoured various resource, but I can't find anything definitive.

I essentially need to replace characters in one of record types with "*" where applicable. I'm hoping someone may be able to provide some guidance and/or documentation that covers this step. As I cannot insert this data into the database and then apply an update query. So alternate solutions aren't an option. Also don't want to use an archaic method like Excel to update the flat files before running it through the ETL process. This one step is a new one for me.

I'm using SSIS/SSDT to do the ETL process. If you know of any quirks relating to my scenario that vary from the normal process (flat file, fixed width, etc.), that'd be helpful.

Any assistance anyone provides is greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Can you show some example data and the intended change? From the description, you could try using a derived column transformation to replace that character before loading into the source.

Comment: I'm working with sensitive data, so I need to create a file with similar details, and replace the concerning parts. May take a moment, but I'll try to get this done as soon as possible.

I appreciate the quick response!